# SQL Convert Int to Time

Tags: sql, time, int

i'm trying to import data from a text file to an SQL database.  The file is using TAB not , to separate fields.  My issue on import has been that when I write the Time which is given as an Int it completely messes up on import.

Part of the text file:

```
North   Felix   2011-07-01  0422    0.47    0012    0.69    2109    0.55    1311    1.44
North   Felix   2011-07-02  0459    0.43    0048    0.72    2140    0.55    1342    1.47
North   Felix   2011-07-03  0533    0.41    0123    0.75    2213    0.57    1412    1.46
North   Felix   2011-07-04  0605    0.41    0158    0.79    2244    0.59    1441    1.41
```

My query result:

```
INSERT INTO `dbc`.`history_long` (`Region`,`Location`,`Date`,`LT1-time`,`LT1-height`,`HT1-time`,`HT1-height`,`LT2-time`,`LT2-height`,`HT2-time`,`HT2-height`) 
values ('North','Felix','2011:00:00','422:00:00','0.47','12:00:00','0.69','2109:00:00','0.55','1311:00:00','1.44'),
('North','Felix','2011:00:00','459:00:00','0.43','48:00:00','0.72','2140:00:00','0.55','1342:00:00','1.47'),
('North','Felix','2011:00:00','533:00:00','0.41','123:00:00','0.75','2213:00:00','0.57','1412:00:00','1.46'),
('North','Felix','2011:00:00','605:00:00','0.41','158:00:00','0.79','2244:00:00','0.59','1441:00:00','1.41'),
```

The issue is for example L2-time becomes 2109:00:00 in the time column.  Is there a way to convert this from Int to Time?

Comment: That can't possibly be *close* to your real query, unless you're using the fruitiest SQL implementation I've ever seen. Column names are separated by commas in the column list of an insert statement, and the separate column values are usually provided as separate parameters and/or literals (again, separated by commas). So what SQL product are you using?

Comment: ...and provide real code with real date

Comment: Sorry, hopefully that's better. Take a look now, and you can see the data i'm reading from, the 4 lines up the top.  I'm importing it in to Navicat at the moment, and that's the query result i'm finishing off with.

I manually wrote a query as well, similar to what Navicat produces but only using the full INT without the : to separate hours:minutes:seconds, and the database won't accept it as it the Time columns are set to use time, so it just screws up.

The source (text file) has about 160,000 lines of data in it, all TAB separated and the time is all given as a 4 digit 24 hours INT.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could convert an `int` like `0422` to a `time` value:

```
SELECT CAST('00:00' AS time)
     + INTERVAL (@IntValue DIV 60) HOUR
     + INTERVAL (@IntValue % 60) MINUTE
```

Without seeing your import query it's impossible to say how you could actually apply it.